# Git: How to rebase a bare repo

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm using [backup software](https://github.com/ytti/oxidized) that makes commits directly to a bare repository by editing the index, rather than updating files in a work directory.

I want the commits to be pushed to a repository on github, so I've cloned my repo as a bare repository and pointed the backup utility at it.  It creates commits just fine which I can push to github as long as the repo hasn't changed upstream.

If the repo does have upstream changes, git won't let me push because of the merge conflict, but I'm also not able to pull/rebase because the bare repository has no work directory to stage the changes.

Everything I can find basically indicates that I should clone the repo so that it has a work tree, but the software I'm using limits my ability to do that.  I tried and when it's pointed at a bare repository the changes it makes don't show up in the work directory so git is confused and thinks files are missing.

Hopefully someone more knowledgable than I can shed some light on this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've also dealt with a bare repo of my own, in between upstream changes made by others and my downstream changes.

To merge upstream changes, I create a second repo of the upstream that is not bare, tie it to my local bare repo, resolve and push.

It's a bit of work and I wouldn't recommend this setup if there is a lot of merging of local and upstream changes - you want an actual work directory to do the merging!

An aside: this confused me, originally it sounded like a bad idea; see the comments below for clarification:

> makes commits directly to a bare repository by editing the index, rather than updating files in a work directory

Comment: > One last thought, this sounds like a bad idea...
You are saying nonsense, and without even explaining your point. What you quoted is precisely what a bare git repo is. You're basically saying bare repositories are a bad idea, well you shouldn't use any remote git repo then, because that's what they are. You misunderstood the sentence, it's not editing the index of the original repo, it just commits to the bare repo copy for back up. That's completely sensible and precisely what remote git repo are doing.

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks for clarifying the OP's sentence, I didn't research it myself, I get what you are saying.  Also I agree, this was just a bad rant!  I'll try to clean it up.

Comment: Well thanks for your understanding answer, and sorry for having been a bit aggressive in my original comment. Have a good day !

Comment: You too my friend!

Answer (score 0):

2024 (8+ years later): you can rebase branches in a bare repository!

You would use a combination of:

- **`git replay`** (new in Git 2.44, Q1 2024)
- [`git update-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-ref) (that [`git rebase --update-refs`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73429249/6309) knows how to use since Git 2.38)

Git 2.44 (Q1 2024) introduces "[`git replay`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/02230b74e8a7c83a7dd57da2e7a299dbb4174f33/Documentation/git-replay.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replay))</sup>, a tool meant on the server side without working tree to recreate a history.

See [commit e928c11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e928c11e29966b0a8f4340465b8238501c994eb1), [commit c461113](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c4611130f47242af19fbd8eca2be039742c122b1), [commit 22d99f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22d99f012f9b33ede37c47a195bad7c12dae596b), [commit 3916ec3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3916ec307eda00d1aab23cf8d1b6ddc5c4f3601d), [commit 81613be](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81613be31e0bedf8709fa0962f1b6f85dcb053a2), [commit fda7dea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fda7dea7c95a7958d36ead75116c1ffbf1791cc0), [commit 4a37727](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a37727626ae60c1e791c243679bc8d437052ee4), [commit 38283bc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/38283bced8bc75f12af7bc0d0a9b135d7f42beea), [commit 8259e41](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8259e4154f46de5b3443a3ff7b1cc4441ec6b7df), [commit e787e66](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e787e664da640d1d4b15c6dc67a704dfa56592f9), [commit a9df61a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9df61ace31b84c9609dfa4875e93b8c92e06e56), [commit d46da6d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d46da6d90be99f91988eececd5368170b0eded1f), [commit f920b02](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f920b0289ba3971451a1cd478baa1d4fddbb0a0b), [commit b9d0991](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9d0991cc702204e14e65abf95d5fc24305e542b) (24 Nov 2023) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 02230b7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/02230b74e8a7c83a7dd57da2e7a299dbb4174f33), 18 Dec 2023)</sup>

> ### [`replay`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81613be31e0bedf8709fa0962f1b6f85dcb053a2): make it a minimal server side command
>
> <sup>Co-authored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Christian Couder</sup>

> We want this command to be a minimal command that just does server side picking of commits, displaying the results on stdout for higher level scripts to consume.
>
> So let's simplify it:
>
> - remove the worktree and index reading/writing,
> - remove the ref (and reflog) updating,
> - remove the assumptions tying us to HEAD, since (a) this is not a rebase and (b) we want to be able to pick commits in a bare repo, i.e.
>   to/from branches that are not checked out and not the main branch,
> - remove unneeded includes,
> - handle rebasing multiple branches by printing on stdout the update ref commands that should be performed.
>
> The output can be piped into [`git update-ref`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/81613be31e0bedf8709fa0962f1b6f85dcb053a2/Documentation/git-update-ref.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-ref))</sup> `--stdin` for the ref updates to happen.
>
> In the future to make it easier for users to use this command directly maybe an option can be added to automatically pipe its output into `git update-ref`.

[Man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c4611130f47242af19fbd8eca2be039742c122b1/Documentation/git-replay.txt)

```
git replay ([--contained] --onto <newbase> | --advance <branch>) <revision-range>...
```

### DESCRIPTION

Takes ranges of commits and replays them onto a new location. Leaves
the working tree and the index untouched, and updates no references.
The output of this command is meant to be used as input to
`git update-ref --stdin`, which would update the relevant branches
(see the OUTPUT section below).

Q1 2024: THIS COMMAND IS EXPERIMENTAL. THE BEHAVIOR MAY CHANGE.

### OPTIONS

`--onto <newbase>`: Starting point at which to create the new commits.  May be any valid commit, and not just an existing branch name.

When `--onto` is specified, the update-ref command(s) in the output will
update the branch(es) in the revision range to point at the new
commits, similar to the way how `git rebase --update-refs` updates
multiple branches in the affected range.

`--advance <branch>`: Starting point at which to create the new commits; must be a branch name.

When `--advance` is specified, the update-ref command(s) in the output
will update the branch passed as an argument to `--advance` to point at
the new commits (in other words, this mimics a cherry-pick operation).

`<revision-range>`: Range of commits to replay. More than one  can be passed, but in `--advance <branch>` mode, they should have a single tip so that it's clear where `<branch>` should point to.
See "Specifying Ranges" in linkgit:git-rev-parse and the "Commit Limiting" options below.

### OUTPUT

When there are no conflicts, the output of this command is usable as
input to `git update-ref --stdin`.
It is of the form:

```bash
update refs/heads/branch1 ${NEW_branch1_HASH} ${OLD_branch1_HASH}
update refs/heads/branch2 ${NEW_branch2_HASH} ${OLD_branch2_HASH}
update refs/heads/branch3 ${NEW_branch3_HASH} ${OLD_branch3_HASH}
```

where the number of refs updated depends on the arguments passed and
the shape of the history being replayed.  When using `--advance`, the number of refs updated is always one, but for `--onto`, it can be one or more (rebasing multiple branches simultaneously is supported).

### EXIT STATUS

For a successful, non-conflicted replay, the exit status is 0.  When
the replay has conflicts, the exit status is 1.  If the replay is not
able to complete (or start) due to some kind of error, the exit status
is something other than 0 or 1.

### EXAMPLES

To simply rebase `mybranch` onto `target`:

```bash
$ git replay --onto target origin/main..mybranch
update refs/heads/mybranch ${NEW_mybranch_HASH} ${OLD_mybranch_HASH}
```

To cherry-pick the commits from mybranch onto target:

```bash
$ git replay --advance target origin/main..mybranch
update refs/heads/target ${NEW_target_HASH} ${OLD_target_HASH}
```

Note that the first two examples replay the same commits and on
top of the same new base, they only differ in that the first
provides instructions to make `mybranch` point at the new commits and
the second provides instructions to make `target` point at them.

What if you have a stack of branches, one depending upon another, and
you'd really like to rebase the whole set?

```bash
$ git replay --contained --onto origin/main origin/main..tipbranch
update refs/heads/branch1 ${NEW_branch1_HASH} ${OLD_branch1_HASH}
update refs/heads/branch2 ${NEW_branch2_HASH} ${OLD_branch2_HASH}
update refs/heads/tipbranch ${NEW_tipbranch_HASH} ${OLD_tipbranch_HASH}
```

When calling `git replay`, one does not need to specify a range of
commits to replay using the syntax `A..B`; any range expression will
do:

```bash
$ git replay --onto origin/main ^base branch1 branch2 branch3
update refs/heads/branch1 ${NEW_branch1_HASH} ${OLD_branch1_HASH}
update refs/heads/branch2 ${NEW_branch2_HASH} ${OLD_branch2_HASH}
update refs/heads/branch3 ${NEW_branch3_HASH} ${OLD_branch3_HASH}
```

This will simultaneously rebase `branch1`, `branch2`, and `branch3`,
all commits they have since `base`, playing them on top of
`origin/main`. These three branches may have commits on top of `base`
that they have in common, but that does not need to be the case.