# Git interactive rebase: how to move other branches (refs) automatically?

Tags: git, rebase

Sometimes I would like to do a rebase and make sure other refs are updated to the new structure without manual resets or multiple rebases.

Is there a way to do it in one go, so that git rebase would update refs to new commit that are picked and had references before rebase?

One example:

Situation before Rebase:

```
* abc3... commit3 (branch:a, HEAD) 
* abc2... commit2 
* abc1... commit1 (branch:b)
* abc0... base commmit (branch:master)
```

Then do a Rebase master -i: pick abc3, abc1, abc2

And the result will look like: (branch:b stays in its own branch of commit)

```
* abc6... commit2 (branch:a, HEAD) 
* abc5... commit1   
* abc4... commit3
|
| * abc1... commit1 (branch:b)
|/
* abc0... base commmit (branch:master)
```

What I would like the result to look like: (branch:b is updated to a new commit)

```
* abc6... commit2 (branch:a, HEAD) 
* abc5... commit1 (branch:b)
* abc4... commit3
* abc0... base commmit (branch:master)
```

Comment: Hey @torek is your comment here outdated? I think git's new `update-refs` feature solves this. (Released in v2.38 just a few months ago)

Comment: @DevinRhode: **yes**, it is outdated, but the update refs feature has a problem as currently implemented, so I don't recommend it yet. (The problem is that if you edit the instruction sheet to remove the update, Git winds up *deleting* the ref. There's a fix in Git 2.39 and 2.38.2, but until it's been out for at least a few months, preferably a year or so, I won't be recommending it.)

Comment: oof, I called that out in my answer. TY!

Comment: I think I noticed a bug with dropping in a `update-refs` line into your `git-rebase-todo`. If you have a worktree that has checked out `old-pr`, in another worktree you have "new-work-on-old-pr", and you are rebasing "new-work-on-old-pr" inside it's respective worktree, dropping a `update-refs refs/heads/old-pr` line inside your git-rebase-todo file led to the `old-pr` worktree getting put into a weird state with many "incoming" changes left in the working directory (quite strange dirty git status)

Comment: ...I am using git-branchless now, a wrapper around git. The bug is probably due to using that.

Answer (score 9):

## Here is the general case of how git 2.39's new `update-refs` feature helps my rebase flow.

<sub>This feature is actually available from git 2.38, but it [****had some bugs****](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72346336/git-interactive-rebase-how-to-move-other-branches-refs-automatically?noredirect=1#comment132136498_72346336) - you should update to `2.39.0`</sub>

#### First you should enable this feature with this config setting:

```bash
git config --global rebase.updateRefs true
```

While doing an interactive rebase, you can now easily tag any commit with a branch name. That branch name also does not need to already exist. This can make it easy to breakup a large sequence of commits into small PRs.

Given you run `git rebase -i <base sha from master>`, inside `git-rebase-todo` file:

```
pick 1688e8706 First
pick d8e19832e Second
pick b34be474e Third
```

You can "tag" each commit with a new branch name, and then push those branches, like so:

```
pick 1688e8706 First
update-ref refs/heads/first

pick d8e19832e Second
update-ref refs/heads/second

pick b34be474e Third
update-ref refs/heads/third
```

### Note: You can mostly ignore the `refs/heads/` prefix, everything after that is the *actual branch name!*

This is how git will edit the file for you, if you already have these branches pointing to these shas. You only have to do this once[1], to tie a branch name to a commit. Then, if you set `git config rebase.updateRefs true`, git-rebase will then automatically drop these `update-ref refs/heads/branch-name` lines into your git-rebase-todo file for you.

Then, after each rebase successfully completes, you'll see:

```
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/third
Updated the following refs with --update-refs:
        refs/heads/first
        refs/heads/second
        refs/heads/third
```

Then you can push each branch like so:

```
git push --force-with-lease origin first:refs/heads/first
git push --force-with-lease origin second:refs/heads/second
git push --force-with-lease origin third:refs/heads/third
git push --force-with-lease origin $(git branch --show-current):refs/heads/$(git branch --show-current)
```

##### Giving commits a stable handle is not radical by itself, but it's a manual step that would be horribly error-prone to do in userland. Now that git has implemented this, watch for higher level tools to give you whole new features!

[1]: If you `git checkout second` and then make changes, git will not update `third`. You should generally prefer to stay on the top of your stack, `third` in this case. If you do make changes to `second` and eventually want to rebase `third`, you should run:

```
git checkout third
git rebase --onto second d8e19832e
```

NOTE: `d8e19832e` is actually correct in this case, given my examples, this is the *original* sha from `second` in the history of `third`. Git rebase will take `d8e19832e` and everything below it, and throw it away, and try to apply the commit "Third" on the new `second`, and you may need to resolve conflicts along the way.

Comment: Good illustration of the feature I mentioned. Upvoted.

Comment: Is there a way to push "previous refs" without specifying them. Currently one need to use a command like `git push --atomic origin first second third` ?

Comment: @bric3 I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for - maybe you're wondering if git could introduce a `rebase.autoPushUpdatedRefs` feature?

Comment: @DevinRhode Yes exactly. Could be with an explicit push option. And only on the current branch.

Comment: Git-branchless is a wrapper around git that could implement such a feature. I would love this feature too! I've filed issues with ideas on their github before and they were pretty friendly :) https://github.com/arxanas/git-branchless

Answer (score 1):

> git rebase would update refs to new commit that are picked and had references *before* rebase?

Before, no.

But while you are rebasing? Maybe.

With Git 2.38 (Q3 2022), "[`git rebase -i`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3d8e3dc4fc22fe41f8ee1184f085c600f35ec76f/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L504)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--i))</sup> learns to update branches whose tip appear in the rebased range with `--update-refs` option.

See [commit 7fefa1b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7fefa1b68ee171db0de966b7dfdcba741b3f2ddf) (12 Jul 2022) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit 4611884](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4611884ea883908a9638cafbd824c401c41cf7f6), [commit aa37f3e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aa37f3e1d892698276b52f347c6374499f6c0759), [commit 3113fed](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3113fedaeb67eed4c46ef7bdd670b8406317a303), [commit b3b1a21](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3b1a21d1a5df87e81fa8b53c6c3cf9760ca12d4), [commit 89fc0b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/89fc0b53fdb4ea2f9581ea728577f4d2a4947672), [commit 900b50c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/900b50c242dfa6b47033cbb495d2fd9d06752ff1), [commit a97d791](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a97d79163e16e2d3777ab4d86c8f006f260c2836), [commit d7ce9a2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d7ce9a220196b995117252bb236baf135c9b704f), [commit f57fd48](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f57fd48d56864ed9a09d65cffe2c70b86ca7b652), [commit aa7f2fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aa7f2fd150e7817de6c781dc5911d6c85f334324), [commit 18ea595](https://github.com/git/git/commit/18ea59582778bd0b80fc643bc4e2981275d2300d), [commit 1bec4d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1bec4d1dfd68653c6590a0cf0bf12831810bc21e) (19 Jul 2022) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3d8e3dc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d8e3dc4fc22fe41f8ee1184f085c600f35ec76f), 01 Aug 2022)</sup>

> ### [`rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/900b50c242dfa6b47033cbb495d2fd9d06752ff1): add --update-refs option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> When working on a large feature, it can be helpful to break that feature into multiple smaller parts that become reviewed in sequence.
> During development or during review, a change to one part of the feature could affect multiple of these parts.
> An interactive rebase can help adjust the multi-part "story" of the branch.
>
> However, if there are branches tracking the different parts of the feature, then rebasing the entire list of commits can create commits not reachable from those "sub branches".
> It can take a manual step to update those branches.
>
> Add a new `--update-refs` option to '[`git rebase -i`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/900b50c242dfa6b47033cbb495d2fd9d06752ff1/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L502)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--i))</sup> that adds 'update-ref ' steps to the todo file whenever a commit that is being rebased is decorated with that .
> At the very end, the rebase process updates all of the listed refs to the values stored during the rebase operation.
>
> Be sure to iterate after any squashing or fixups are placed.
> Update the branch only after those squashes and fixups are complete.
> This allows a `--fixup` commit at the tip of the feature to apply correctly to the sub branch, even if it is fixing up the most-recent commit in that part.
>
> This change update the documentation and builtin to accept the `--update-refs` option as well as updating the todo file with the 'update-ref' commands.
> Tests are added to ensure that these todo commands are added in the correct locations.
>
> This change does *not* include the actual behavior of tracking the updated refs and writing the new ref values at the end of the rebase process.
> That is deferred to a later change.

`git rebase` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/900b50c242dfa6b47033cbb495d2fd9d06752ff1/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L612-L617):

> ### `--update-refs`
>
> ### `--no-update-refs`
>
> Automatically force-update any branches that point to commits that
> are being rebased.
> Any branches that are checked out in a worktree
> are not updated in this way.

And:

> ### [`rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/89fc0b53fdb4ea2f9581ea728577f4d2a4947672): update refs from 'update-ref' commands
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> The previous change introduced the '[`git rebase --update-refs`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89fc0b53fdb4ea2f9581ea728577f4d2a4947672/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L612)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---update-refs))</sup> option which added '`update-ref <ref>`' commands to the `todo` list of an interactive rebase.
>
> Teach Git to record the HEAD position when reaching these 'update-ref' commands.
> The ref/before/after triple is stored in the `$GIT_DIR/rebase-merge/update-refs` file.
> A previous change parsed this file to avoid having other processes updating the refs in that file while the rebase is in progress.
>
> Not only do we update the file when the sequencer reaches these 'update-ref' commands, we then update the refs themselves at the end of the rebase sequence.
> If the rebase is aborted before this final step, then the refs are not updated.
> The 'before' value is used to ensure that we do not accidentally obliterate a ref that was updated concurrently (say, by an older version of Git or a third-party tool).

Result:

> ### [`sequencer`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4611884ea883908a9638cafbd824c401c41cf7f6): notify user of `--update-refs` activity
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Elijah Newren</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> When the user runs '[`git rebase -i --update-refs`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4611884ea883908a9638cafbd824c401c41cf7f6/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L502)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--i))</sup>, the end message still says only
>
> ```
> Successfully rebased and updated <HEAD-ref>.
> ```
>
> Update the sequencer to collect the successful (and unsuccessful) ref updates due to the `--update-refs` option, so the end message now says
>
> ```
> Successfully rebased and updated <HEAD-ref>.
> Updated the following refs with --update-refs:
> efs/heads/first
> efs/heads/third
> Failed to update the following refs with --update-refs:
> efs/heads/second
> ```

---

[`git rebase --update-refs`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/35dc2cf03fdb5de830f2194d86b0eea8367ed1e4/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L618)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---update-refs))</sup> would delete references when all `update-ref` commands in the sequencer were removed, which has been corrected with Git 2.39 (Q4 2022).

See [commit 44da9e0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44da9e08413ec6a579ce4238acf1937b333836fe) (07 Nov 2022) by [Victoria Dye (`vdye`)](https://github.com/vdye).
<sup>(Merged by [Taylor Blau -- `ttaylorr` --](https://github.com/ttaylorr) in [commit 35dc2cf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35dc2cf03fdb5de830f2194d86b0eea8367ed1e4), 18 Nov 2022)</sup>

> ### [`rebase --update-refs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44da9e08413ec6a579ce4238acf1937b333836fe): avoid unintended ref deletion
>
> <sup>Reported-by: herr.kaste</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Phillip Wood</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Victoria Dye</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> In [b3b1a21](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3b1a21d1a5df87e81fa8b53c6c3cf9760ca12d4) ("`sequencer`: rewrite update-refs as user edits todo list", 2022-07-19, Git v2.38.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d8e3dc4fc22fe41f8ee1184f085c600f35ec76f) listed in [batch #8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/350dc9f0e8974b6fcbdeb3808186c5a79c3e7386)), the '`todo_list_filter_update_refs()`' step was added to handle the removal of '`update-ref`' lines from a '`rebase-todo`'.
> Specifically, it removes potential ref updates from the "`update refs state`" if a ref does not have a corresponding '`update-ref`' line.
>
> However, because '`write_update_refs_state()`' will not update the state if the '`refs_to_oids`' list was empty, removing *all* '`update-ref`' lines will result in the state remaining unchanged from how it was initialized (with all refs' "after" OID being null).
> Then, when the ref update is applied, all refs will be updated to null and consequently deleted.
>
> To fix this, delete the 'update-refs' state file when '`refs_to_oids`' is empty.
> Additionally, add a tests covering "all update-ref lines removed" cases.

Comment: Yes, but watch out for the bug (fixed in 2.39 and 2.38.2) where update-refs can *delete* a ref...

Comment: @torek Do you have a reference for that bug?

Comment: No, but it's in the release notes. Let's see what `git log` finds ... aha, [`93a7bc8b285eaad24049bc862b4733d595a473f8`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93a7bc8b285eaad24049bc862b4733d595a473f8) Oh, I see you already found it too!

Comment: @torek But... that is the same commit content I already mention at the end of this answer. (Cherry-picked for 2.38.2)